# Exploiting malloc by specifying number of elems

Tags: c, exploit

I'm trying to understand this heap overflow exploit. Say I have the following code:

```
struct data *arr = malloc(sizeof(struct data)*numElems);
/*... use arr[0], arr[1], etc if arr is not NULL*/
```

The attacker has control over numElems.
I understand this can be exploited by causing a heap overflow to write into arbitrary pointer addresses in the metadata of free chunks. But how is this? The memory given to us by malloc is safe so I'm assuming `arr[numElems-n]` `(n>0;n<=numElems)` is also safe. Does the exploit come from accessing `arr[numElems]` and write into the next block's space?

Comment: What happens if the calculation `sizeof(struct data)*numElems` overflows?

Comment: Oh, are you suggesting to specify a numElem which will cause interger overflow in such a way that we can access a free chunk?

Comment: `arr[numElements]` is not allocated. Use valgrind to detect Invalid Read.